operation on document whose parent document is being deleted not working in cloud functions
I have collections of users and posts. The data structure looks something like this below.
/root
    /users (collection)
        /user_id_a (document with fields)
            - user_id_a
            - user_name_aa
            /my_post_list (collection)
                /first_list (document with fields)
                    - actual_list // lets say actual_list have post_id_c in the list => actual_list[post_id_c]

    /posts (collection)
        /post_id_c (document with fields)
            - post_id_c
            - post_title
            - posted_by
            - created_at

What I am trying to do is to delete "document of post_id_c and sub collection of post_id_c" based on document user_id_a deletion(which means delete all posts that have written by a user that is being deleted). I want this behavior with cloud functions for firebase with code below.
export const onUserDeleted_v0 = onDocumentDeleted(
  "users/{userUid}",
  async (event) => {
    // Get an object representing the document
    const snapshot = event.data!;
    if (!snapshot) {
      console.log("No data associated with the event");
      return;
    }
    const userData = snapshot.data();

    const docFirstListSnapshot = await admin.firestore()
      .collection('users')
      .doc(event.params.userUid) // where user_id_a being used according to data structure above.
      .collection('my_post_list')
      .doc('first_list').get();
    console.log("docFirstListSnapshot is: " + util.inspect(docFirstListSnapshot)); // look below for this log.

    if (docFirstListSnapshot.exists) {
      const documentIdsList = docFirstListSnapshot.data()!.actual_list;

      for (var index in documentIdsList) {
        const ref = admin.firestore()
          .collection('posts').doc(documentIdsList[index])

        await admin.firestore().recursiveDelete(ref);
      }
    } else {
      console.log("failed to get my post document ids list of " + event.params.userUid);
    }
  });

and this is what i see on server side log.
docFirstListSnapshot is: DocumentSnapshot {
_fieldsProto: undefined,
_ref: DocumentReference {
_firestore: Firestore {
_settings: [Object],
_settingsFrozen: true,
_serializer: [Serializer],
_projectId: 'my-project-name',
_databaseId: '(default)',
registeredListenersCount: 0,
bulkWritersCount: 0,
_backoffSettings: [Object],
_clientPool: [ClientPool],
_gax: [Object]
},
_path: ResourcePath { segments: [Array] },
_converter: {
toFirestore: [Function: toFirestore],
fromFirestore: [Function: fromFirestore]
}
},
_serializer: Serializer {
createReference: [Function (anonymous)],
createInteger: [Function (anonymous)],
allowUndefined: false
},
_readTime: Timestamp { _seconds: 1717121572, _nanoseconds: 3938000 },
_createTime: undefined,
_updateTime: undefined
}

I see docFirstListSnapshot has some contents when logging it with util.inspect(docFirstListSnapshot) in cloud functions but docFirstListSnapshot.exist prints false. Is this something impossible to achieve? or Am I missing anything?

Please include the util.inspect(docFirstListSnapshot)  statement and its output in the question.

@FrankvanPuffelen I updated my post as you suggests. I will appreciate your help.

That looks like a valid DocumentSnapshot object, but if its exists is true it means that no actual document exists in the location you're trying to read.
